# How to join with lowercase column values in a spark DF

Tags: scala, apache-spark

```
 val df_final = Data1
        .join(broadcast(df),
          Seq(lower(col("NAME")),  lower(col("TYPE"))),
          "left")
```

The above code is throwing the below error.

```
<console>:65: error: overloaded method value join with alternatives:
  (right: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[_],joinExprs: org.apache.spark.sql.Column,joinType: String)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame <and>
  (right: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[_],usingColumns: Seq[String],joinType: String)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
 cannot be applied to (org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row], Seq[org.apache.spark.sql.Column], String)
               .join(broadcast(df),
            ^
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use *inbuilt functions* inside *condition* sequence, instead you can do the following

```
 val df_final = Data1
        .join(broadcast(df),
          lower(col("NAME")) === lower(col("TYPE")),
          "left")
```

Comment: `val df_final = Data1
    .as("base")
    .join(
      broadcast(df).as("lookup"),
      lower(col("base.NAME")) === lower(col("lookup.NAME")) && lower(
        col("base.TYPE")) === lower(
        col("lookup.TYPE")),
      "left"
    )` Doing this keep duplicate columns in resultant DF, how to get rid of duplicates.

Comment: to remove the duplicates you can do dropDuplicates which will consider all the columns. and I think you can pass column names too

Comment: Had to rename the columns. Dropping duplicates will drop both the columns

Comment: Ok I misunderstood, so you wanted to avoid the duplicate column names.  you can use select if you want only one column and use alias if you want both columns with different names

Comment: `val df_final = Data1 .as("base") .join( broadcast(df).as("lookup"), lower(col("base.NAME")) === lower(col("lookup.NAME")) && lower( col("base.TYPE")) === lower( col("lookup.TYPE")), "left" ).select(col("base.NAME"), col("base.TYPE"))` this will select only two columns of Data1 after join. this is an example of select

Comment: `val df_final = Data1 .as("base") .join( broadcast(df).as("lookup"), lower(col("base.NAME")) === lower(col("lookup.NAME")) && lower( col("base.TYPE")) === lower( col("lookup.TYPE")), "left" ).select(col("base.NAME"), col("base.TYPE"), col("lookup.NAME").as("lookupName"), col("lookup.TYPE").as("lookupType"))`. now this is an example of select and alias